# Find and remove a string starting and ending with a specific numbers in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to extract and store characters as strings into a list from a text, given x and y character positions? Example:

```
Text = [
who makes bromocriptinei am wondering what company makes the drug bromocriptine, i need it for a mass i have on my pituitary gland and the cost just keeps raising. i cannot ever buy a full prescription because of the price and i was told if i get a hold of the maker of the drug sometimes they offer coupons or something to help me afford the medicine. if i buy 10 pills in which i have to take 2 times a day it costs me 78.00. and that is how i have to buy them.  thanks. ]

positions = [[10,24],[66,79]]

transform [positions]

print(transform)

output:

[bromocriptinei, bromocriptine]
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: What do you mean by *x,y* positions? The starting and the ending of a string

Comment: This is basic string slicing: `output = [text[x:y] for x,y in pos]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the text directly:

```
txt = "who makes bromocriptinei am wondering what company makes the drug bromocriptine, i need it for a mass i have on my pituitary gland and the cost just keeps raising. i cannot ever buy a full prescription because of the price and i was told if i get a hold of the maker of the drug sometimes they offer coupons or something to help me afford the medicine. if i buy 10 pills in which i have to take 2 times a day it costs me 78.00. and that is how i have to buy them.  thanks."

positions = [txt[10: 24], txt[66: 79]]
# ['bromocriptinei', 'bromocriptine']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solved my question. Further developing on this idea, is it also possible to instead use the list index as the positions? Example: `positions = [txt[position[0]], txt[position[1]]`

Comment: @LuiHellesoe yes, but it will be more complicated, e.g. look at Piotr's answer. He did that for bromocriptinei. Ann's answer is also good, as she useses this slicing approach in a more automated way. Let me know if you have any more questions. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

List slicing will do it for you. Convert string to list and then use it like that `list[start:end]`

In your example

```
transform = Text[positions[0][0]: positions[0][1]]
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert the string to a list? This is unnecessary as you can just index the strings with the given `[x:y]` positions.

Comment: This outputs `['b', 'r', 'o', 'm', 'o', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'i']`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [list slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html#slicing):

```
Text = "who makes bromocriptinei am wondering what company makes the drug bromocriptine, i need it for a mass i have on my pituitary gland and the cost just keeps raising. i cannot ever buy a full prescription because of the price and i was told if i get a hold of the maker of the drug sometimes they offer coupons or something to help me afford the medicine. if i buy 10 pills in which i have to take 2 times a day it costs me 78.00. and that is how i have to buy them.  thanks."

positions = [[10,24],[66,79]]

def transform(text, pos):
    return [text[i: j] for i, j in positions]

print(transform(Text, positions))
```

Output:

```
['bromocriptinei', 'bromocriptine']
```